# How to force suds to use TLS only?

Tags: python, ssl, suds

I am using python-suds to connect to a SOAP interface. Since a server-side upgrade SSLv3 is no longer enabled and I need to use something else, most likely some TLS version.

The problem is on the client side, I haven't yet been able find a way to make my script force the ancient python and suds versions to use TLS. I've tried looking for a custom ssl module context or a custom suds transport, but haven't been able to find something.

Has anyone solved this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use the suds-request module as transport client for suds for this. Another option is to use the new python zeep module which should handle this automatically (see http://docs.python-zeep.org)